# strtok() and empty fields

Tags: c, strtok

I am serializing some C structure to string and than deserializing it with `strtok()`. But, unfortunately, `strtok()` don't detect empty fields (eg 1:2::4).

Is there any alternative function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On linux there's [strsep](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strsep.3.asp).

> The strsep() function was introduced
>   as a replacement for strtok(), since
>   the latter cannot handle  empty 
>   fields.   However,  strtok()
>          conforms to C89/C99 and hence is more portable.

Comment: strsep() is also thread-safe (or can be made that way), which strtok() is very very not.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `strchr` (for just one delimiter character) or `strcspn` (for a group of possible delimiters) to find the next delimiter, process the token, and then just step one character forward. Do this in a loop and you have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Drakosha gave the correct answer. I want to add an example for both variants.

With strtok:

```
char *token;
char *tmp_string;
char delimiter[10] = " |,.:";
strcpy (tmp_string, "1:2::4");
token = strtok(tmp_string, delimiter); // first token
while(token != NULL) {
    i++;
    printf ("i=%d\tToken: len(%d)\t%s", i, strlen(token), token);
    // do something
    token = strtok(NULL, delimiter); /* next token */
}
```

With strsep (will recognize ""):

```
char *token;
char *tmp_string;
char delimiter[10] = " |,.";
strcpy (tmp_string, "1:2::4");
token = strsep(&tmp_string, delimiter); // first token
while(token != NULL) {
    i++;
    printf ("i=%d\tToken: len(%d)\t%s", i, strlen(token), token);
    // do something
    token = strsep(&tmp_string, delimiter); /* next token */
}
```

Comment: `char *tmp_string;`
`strcpy (tmp_string, "1:2::4");`

will cause memory issues...

Comment: Why not simply on the stack: `char tmp[] = "1:2::4";` - in contrast, the delimiter does not need to be placed there, simply can do `strtok(tmp, ":");`...