# How to detect empty line with strtok

Tags: c, c-strings, strtok

I'm trying to separate a header from a footer separated by an empty line i.e. with the string  "\r\n\r\n".

I have tried using `strtok` with separator `"\r\n\r\n"` as the following code snippet shows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char get[1024] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Tue, 23 Jul 2019 22:52:44 GMT\r\n"
                     "Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)\r\n"
                     "Last-Modified: Wed, 18 Aug 2004 23:07:08 GMT\r\n"
                     "ETag: \"164-3e1f5b9a57f00\"\r\n"
                     "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n"
                     "Content-Length: 356\r\n"
                     "Vary: Accept-Encoding\r\n"
                     "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
                     "\r\n"
                     "<html><head><title>Temporary Page</title></head><body><center><h1>New Account Temporary Page</h1>Welcome to yet another new account at Hurricane Electric.<p><h2>Come Back Soon!</h2>The New Account Owner Will Be Putting Something Interesting Here!</center><hr>Space Provided By <a href=\"http://www.he.net\">Hurricane Electric</a></body></html>";

    char *html;

    html = strtok(get, "\r\n\r\n");
    printf("Header:\n\n%s\n\n", html);
    html = strtok(NULL, "\r\n\r\n");
    printf("HTML:\n\n%s\n\n", html);

    return 1;
}
```

I expect the output to be the header printed out and then the HTML footer.

But ouptut is:

```
Header:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

HTML:

Date: Tue, 23 Jul 2019 22:52:44 GMT
```

It seems that `strtok` is separating using `"\r\n"` rather than `"\r\n\r\n"`. How can I fix this strange behaviour?

Comment: can you also mention the expected output in the question?

Comment: `strtok` probably isn't the right tool for this job.

Comment: If I were you, I would either (a) read lines terminated with `\r\n` or (b) read lines terminated with `\n`, and strip the resulting `\r` at the end of each line.  (And there's no good way in C to do (a), so I'd probably do (b).) Assuming you've stripped both \r` and \n` from the buffer you're reading lines into, a blank line is then the empty string, which you can check for by testing `buf[0] == '\0'`.

Comment: (And when I say "read lines", I'm anticipating the eventual, more realistic version of your HTTP fetcher, when you're actually reading from a socket, not simulating input with that constant array `get`.)

Comment: The other issue with `strtok` is that it's specifically designed to collapse multiple adjacent instances of your delimiter, i.e. it can't return empty "tokens", i.e. in your case it will never return an empty line for you to detect.  There's an "improved" version of `strtok` called `strsep` that is able to handle empty fields if desired, although if you use it, I think you're going to have to use a single `\n` as your delimiter, and then use some other technique to get rid of the `\r`'s.  See [strtok() and empty fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377760).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtok` delimiter argument is not a sequence of chars. It is the list of the possible chars that delimit your tokens.

So passing repeated chars in the delimiter string has not the desired effect.

To convince yourself, replace the delimiter by `GMT`, you'll see that your header is now `H`, because `strtok` tokenized from `T`, as it is in delimiter list.

An alternative (dirty/no error checking) would be to locate the delimiter with `strstr`, put zero there, and print both strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{

    char get[1024] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Tue, 23 Jul 2019 22:52:44 GMT\r\nServer: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)\r\nLast-Modified: Wed, 18 Aug 2004 23:07:08 GMT\r\nETag: \"164-3e1f5b9a57f00\"\r\nAccept-Ranges: bytes\r\nContent-Length: 356\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html><head><title>Temporary Page</title></head><body><center><h1>New Account Temporary Page</h1>Welcome to yet another new account at Hurricane Electric.<p><h2>Come Back Soon!</h2>The New Account Owner Will Be Putting Something Interesting Here!</center><hr>Space Provided By <a href=\"http://www.he.net\">Hurricane Electric</a></body></html>";

    const char *delim = "\r\n\r\n";

    char *html;

    html = strstr(get, delim);  // should test for NULL ...
    html[0] = '\0';
    printf("Header:\n\n%s\n\n", get);
    printf("HTML:\n\n%s\n\n", html+strlen(delim));

    return 1;

}
```

output:

```
Header:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 23 Jul 2019 22:52:44 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Wed, 18 Aug 2004 23:07:08 GMT
ETag: "164-3e1f5b9a57f00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 356
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html

HTML:

<html><head><title>Temporary Page</title></head><body><center><h1>New Account Temporary Page</h1>Welcome to yet another new account at Hurricane Electric.<p><h2>Come Back Soon!</h2>The New Account Owner Will Be Putting Something Interesting Here!</center><hr>Space Provided By <a href="http://www.he.net">Hurricane Electric</a></body></html>
```